# React: Rendering non-existing HTML Element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

While reading the React docs, I realized that in JSX, elements starting with a lowercase letter are treated as HTML element. While putting this into practice, I noticed something interesting: When I pass a non-existing, lowercase element, React renders this just fine.

```
function Foo() {
  return (<foo>hello world</foo>);
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Foo />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

This renders like this:

```
<div id="container">
    <foo data-reactroot="">hello world</foo>
</div>
```

While trying to find an answer on how this is possible, I encountered several projects dealing with Web Components/Custom Elements in React, which confused me a bit.

Does this have something to do with Custom Elements? Will this work in any browser that is supported by React?

Comment: It should work in browsers that support custom elements [MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Custom_Elements)

Answer (score 2):

No, this has nothing to do with Custom Elements.

It's perfectly fine to create an element which has a tag name that doesn't represent any predefined HTML element. You will get an instance of [`HTMLUnknownElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLUnknownElement):

```js
const myElement = document.createElement('foo');
console.log(myElement.nodeName);
console.log(myElement instanceof HTMLUnknownElement);
```

Unknown elements don't have special behavior. If you want create a `<foo>` element which has special behavior, you have to use Custom Elements.

Answer (score 0):

As PeterMader explains, you are creating a custom html element with that syntax. I'll expand on that answer a bit.

---

First of all it's important to understand that JSX is just a syntactic sugar and that it ultimately transpiles into JavaScript. React elements are created with `createElement`.

```
React.createElement(type, props, children);
```

What's important to note here is that `type` can be one of the following:

- A reference to a React Component (e.g `Foo` in your example).
- A string.

If you are writing React ***without JSX***, then it doesn't matter if you reference a component as `foo` or as `Foo` because you have complete control of how you define your variables. In other words, this is plain JavaScript and JSX rules don't apply.

However, if you are using React ***with JSX***, the following rules apply:

- `type` starts with a capital letter = React Component.
- `type` starts with a lowercase letter = HTML element.

In fact, the official documentation says:

> When an element type starts with a lowercase letter, it refers to a built-in component like `<div>` or `<span>` and results in a string `'div'` or `'span'` passed to `React.createElement`. Types that start with a capital letter like `<Foo />` compile to `React.createElement(Foo)` and correspond to a component defined or imported in your JavaScript file.
>
> We recommend naming components with a capital letter. If you do have a component that starts with a lowercase letter, assign it to a capitalized variable before using it in JSX.

---

#### So what about `<foo />`?

In the event that the `type` of a React Element doesn't resolve into a React Component and is not a standard HTML, React will still treat it as an HTML element.

To my knowledge, React actually doesn't have any whitelist of "valid" HTML tags, but treats anything starting with lowercase the same way. The result in your browser may differ though, as per PeterMader's response.

As such, this (JSX):

```
<foo>hello world</foo>
```

will, in modern browsers, yield (HTML):

```
<foo>hello world</foo>
```

which is perfectly fine technically, but probably still not a good idea.